# Inactive areas in weight paint still move no matter what I do

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, weight-paint-mode

Moving the arms on my character deforms the hands for seemingly no reason. In both styles of weight paint view, they are not active whatsoever. I also attempted to manually remove the vertices from the vertex group but it seemingly did not work or did not do anything. I am desperate for help as I have found no solution that works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link, then edit your question and paste the link into it so that we can look at your file.

Comment: You assigned that part of the mesh in that specific vertex group, it doesn't mean that it isn't assigned in another group already. If you look to the other groups, you will probably find out that it's influenced by other bones. That's why enabling Auto Normalize is often recommended, or at least run the normalize operator once in a while.